# Parents' names in their passports are not matching the names in my passport. Do I need to specify 2 names in B2 visa application and other documents?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I am from India. And I am working in the USA on an H-1B visa.

Due to a clerical mistake, my father's education documents have a different last name than his original. Same thing for his job documents also, whereas other sets of documents like birth certificate, residence certificate, etc have his original surname.

The original surname is in all my documents. When I applied for a passport, I got it with the original surname and my father's name also printed with his original surname.

Recently, we applied for passports for my parents. Since the documents required for applying for a passport have the other last name, that name, and not the original surname, is in their passports. So now the last name for my parents in my passport and their passports is different.

So we have made a non-judicial document from a local attorney about these 2 names, which supports the fact of having 2 names for my parents. And also as suggested, we have published a notice in a well-known newspaper about this fact.

Now I am sponsoring a B-2 visa for them. Do I need to specify both names in the visa application and other documents, like the letter to the consulate and invitation letter, or do I need to specify names as per their passport, and explain the reason when my parents go for the visa interview?

Comment: Babu... Did your parents get visa?

Answer (score 8):

No problem, there is a field for "other names" in the visa form, you can fill the other name they have there. That will do. Plus, in many communities parents names have different surnames, and children names can have other names, it is not something totally strange.